# How do you enabled layouts for non-HTML templates in Symfony?

Tags: symfony1

### My Example

Relatively simple layout.xml.php:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="<?php echo sfConfig::get('sf_charset', 'UTF-8') ?>"?>
<example>
  <?php echo $sf_content ?>
</example>
```

Simply isn't being used by any XML templates e.g. indexSuccess.xml.php

---

### The Symfony documentation states:

> The layout is automatically disabled for XML HTTP requests and non-HTML content types, unless explicitly set for the view.

Yet gives no documentation on how to set explcitly? Elsewhere obviously leads to:

```
all:
  layout: layout
  has_layout: true
```

But this seems to make no difference for XML templates?

Other sources mention sfAction having a hasLayout method, which clearly has been deprecated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Evidently seems this isn't something that can be set globally via YAML (which is sad).

You can set it as stated in the documentation per view, i.e. in view.yml:

```
indexSuccess:
  layout: layout
  has_layout
```

But this is pretty laborious if you have many actions and against DRY concepts.
Note: Setting the values for `all` takes no effect.

```
$this->setLayout('layout')
```

Does work within an action, but again in my scenario this would need to be set in *every* action, again not particularly DRY.

Thus, I chose to extend sfActions and bind it into the preExecute method.

```
class myActions extends sfActions {
  public function execute($request) {
    if($request->getRequestFormat() == 'xml') {
      $this->setLayout('layout');
    }
    return parent::execute($request);
  }
}
```

Sorts the problem globally if you make sure all your actions extend `myActions` instead of `sfActions`, if you want to do it for all formats you could make use of the `preExecute` method instead, but I wanted to make use of the `sfWebRequest` to ensure I don't try and force layouts onto prospective other formats I may add such as JSON.

Answer (score 0):

Might this be part of "setting it explicitly for the view"?

```
$response = $this->getResponse();
$response->setContentType('text/xml');
```

http://www.symfony-project.org/gentle-introduction/1_4/en/07-Inside-the-View-Layer

Comment: Content type will already be set to text/xml based on the routing, setting it wouldn't amend the issue anyway- the problem is that non-HTML types do not use a layout.

Comment: Ah, now I see what you're trying to do. Yes, I think this setLayout() is the "explicit" way. I guess you could also use fragments... either use a template as a layout and fill it with components, or two partials as they layout header/footer. Not as nice as a real layout though.

Comment: I'm fairly happy with the answer I posted, whilst it's not as nice as throwing something into YAML it still enables a layout globally for XML :)